# Upload to Amazon EC2 as root using Sublime Text SFTP Plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sublimetext2, sftp, scp

Under Windows, how can you configure Sublime Text's FTP plugin to use an SSH key to upload files to the EC2 server via SFTP as the `root` user?

I am getting `Connection Timeout` error using the following config in `sftp-config.json`:

```
"type": "sftp",
"host": "ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
"user": "root",
"ssh_key_file": "F:\\SSH Keys\\aws\\xxx.ppk",
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which plugin you talking about my guess is you are thinking FTP and sFTP are same protocols. They are not the same protocols http://www.wise-ftp.com/know-how/ftp_and_sftp.htm
, you need something that can handle sftp like http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp

or checkout free tools like cyberduck http://cyberduck.ch/ or winscp http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you set "remote_path" to the web root? Also, are you sure you can login as the root user, rather than "ec2-user" or "ubuntu" or something specific to the instance you chose? This [blog post](http://www.habdas.org/sftp-to-ubuntu-server-sublime-text/) gives an extensive tutorial if the first suggestions don't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Security Group accepts SSH inbound traffic.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be getting a timeout error if your server is configured properly. A timeout error would imply that you can't connect to port 22 for some reason.
Have you tried using a normal password to connect too? I don't know if your SFTP plugin supports PPK files.